# advanced ip scanner cant find raspberry pi ip address

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wie4p.png)Following things I have done :

I downloaded raspberry pi os on sd card using "Raspi Card Image" Inserted sd card to raspberry pi and connected ethernet cable and power cable(mobile charging cable usb-type-c cable to power it) But when I connected all this , I got the ethernet ip address from network and sharing center as follows : 192.168.137.1 I used advanced ip scanner to scan in range of 192.168.137.1-192.168.137.254. But still I am not getting raspberry pi in the results.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

did you connect the pi using laptop with a ethernet cable?, well first try to ping the ip using ping command if you didn't got result then (if connected with router using ethernet then use fing[android app to find device model with ip address and mac address] )if connected with laptop then you might have confused with other ips. give a little more detail so i could better understand that

Comment: yes, I connected pi board using ethernet cable. I watched in youtube videos , that pi ip address should be able to come in advanced ip scan results. but its not happening.

Comment: Please check the image I added in question. I got the IP from there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that, the raspberry pi is connected to the internet through wifi or Ethernet. Then, you can check the pi IP address via using the modem interface. like: 192.168.1.1

After that,
You can use ssh connection to try connection between Pi and your notebook.
Make sure, Pi's green indicator is on.
Search bruteforcely :) If your notebook's IP is 192.168.1.200 for example your Pi's ip can be 192.168.1.201. You can iterate the IPs.